# how to send a int from an iPhone to Apple Watch label(objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, apple-watch

so I'm new to iOS development but I've been coding with java for years now.. but I've been trying to figure out how to send an integer, a single number from a variable from the iPhone to a label on an Apple Watch. I'm at the point of banging my head against the keyboard because it seems so easy but I have no idea how implement any of it. thanks for any help,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to send data between iPhone and its paired Apple Watch is through the [Watch Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity) framework - you'll able to send an integer since it's a [property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH44-SW1) type.

Another way is by sending it up to the network and then fetching it from a WiFi or cellular connected Apple Watch. A more complex iPhone + Apple Watch app might make use of both.